# How to store Arduino program with it libraries in git

Tags: git, arduino

I'm trying to find a good way to make Arduino dev env work with git.

How can I write a program in Arduino dev env which uses several libraries and store it in a git so that other people can clone the git repo and start work without manual steps?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules might help

Answer (score 2):

I've created a repo just for that! :)

It's called the [Bare Arduino Project](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project) and it's intended to help you write Arduino programs outside of the IDE, using your favorite text editor like Vim or SublimeText.

It is based on a bigger robotic project I'm working on, [Moti](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/moti), and I thought it could be useful for beginners to have a boiler plate repo they can use for their own project.

I uses Sudar's [Arduino Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) to take care of compilation and uploading.

There is plenty of documentation:

- [README](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project/blob/master/README.md)
- [How to use/install](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project/blob/master/INSTALL.md)

Just fork or clone the repo and you're up and running!

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options

1. Just include a library folder and have them copy it. It isn't ideal, but it takes ten seconds.
2. Create a small script (Java would be ideal for compatibility) that copies the libraries.
3. You can just copy the library files (`keywords.txt`, `.cpp`, and `.h` files) into the root of the sketch folder. The Arduino IDE should look in the main folder before the "libraries" folder. This would look cluttered and the libraries would appear as tabs in the IDE but it requires no extra work.

Without other software there is no real alternative that I am aware of.